# Is it possible to push a link or message through bluetooth to nearby devices?

Tags: mobile, bluetooth, push-notification, wifi

I am trying to develop an add on to my application that will allow my users to push through bluetooth or wifi a link or message to nearby mobile devices which are on.

I have not been able to find any information on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS, yes, you may use airdrop.
For Android, it may be yes but you may need write your own application, i.e. via OPP profile.